# Login failed for User in SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I need to create a user who can execute store procedures only in SQL Server. I use this Query

```
CREATE LOGIN SLogin WITH PASSWORD=N'#######', DEFAULT_DATABASE=MyDB, CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

CREATE USER SUser FOR LOGIN [SLogin] 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = MyDB

CREATE ROLE SUserRole AUTHORIZATION SUser

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, ALTER, EXECUTE TO SUserRole
```

The problem is When I try to login using SSMS with SUser I get a error message "login failed for user" error code 18456. But I can login using SLogin and password.

When I try to execute the Store Procedure from C# if I use this connection String `Data Source=############\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=SLogin;Password=######;`

I am able to open the connection but can't execute the store procedures. It says user do not have access to this schema.

And in the connection string if I use SUser as User ID then I can not open the connection.

Please help me find out where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Start in master and create the login.  In this example, I want them to default to the [BSA] database.

```
-- Which database to use.
USE [master]
GO


-- Delete existing login.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'BSA_ADMIN')
DROP LOGIN [BSA_ADMIN]
GO

-- Add new login.
CREATE LOGIN [BSA_ADMIN] WITH PASSWORD=N'M0a2r0c9h11$', 
    CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[BSA];
GO
```

2 - Switch to database [BSA] and create the user.  In this example, I want them to default schema to be [DBO] and mapped to the above login.

```
-- Which database to use.
USE [BSA]
GO

-- Delete existing user.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'BSA_ADMIN')
DROP USER [BSA_ADMIN]
GO

-- Add new user.
CREATE USER [BSA_ADMIN] FOR LOGIN [BSA_ADMIN] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[DBO]
GO
```

3 - Next, create any roles and add the user to the role.  In this example, the user is added to db_owner.

```
-- Which database to use.
USE [BSA]
GO

-- Add to database owner role 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'BSA_ADMIN'
GO
```

You might be getting the error because the login is defaulting to [master].  This happens often to new DBA's.

4 - Optionally in your case, you can create an custom role and give the role ownership of the schema.

Below code is for a presentation I do.  Just make the necessary changes for your environment.

```
-- Make sure we are in autos
USE [AUTOS]
GO

-- Delete existing role.
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals 
    WHERE type_desc = 'DATABASE_ROLE' AND name = 'AUTO_ROLE')
  DROP ROLE [AUTO_ROLE]
GO

-- Create application role
CREATE ROLE [AUTO_ROLE] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO


-- Apply permissions to schemas
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::[ACTIVE] TO [AUTO_ROLE]
GO

GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[ACTIVE] TO [AUTO_ROLE]
GO

GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[ACTIVE] TO [AUTO_ROLE]
GO

-- Ensure role membership is correct
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'AUTO_ROLE', N'AUTO_USER'
GO
```

Comment: No it didn't solve the problem. With login I am able to establish the connection but can't execute SP. With User I can't open the connection.

Comment: Explicitly add permission of the role to the SP.  Also, test the security via SSMS, login via standard security.  Open a new query window and try to execute the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I somehow get it worked. My Final query is

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [SLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'#####', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MyDB],   CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

CREATE USER SUser FOR LOGIN [SLogin] 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [MyDB]

CREATE ROLE SUserRole AUTHORIZATION SUser

GRANT SELECT, INSERT,EXEC, ALTER TO SurveyUserRole

ALTER ROLE [SUserRole] ADD MEMBER [SUser]
```

But I am confused..

```
CREATE ROLE SUserRole AUTHORIZATION SUser
```

This query supposed to create the role and also assign this role to the user. Why I need to add again user to this role.

Can anyone explain this behavior

Comment: I usually leave that [dbo] then sp_addrolemember, same thing as ADD MEMBER!